Expected identifier error when using static in C
I can’t figure out why it throws an identifier expected error on line 3. Code was compiled using tcc.
#include <stdlib.h>

void genset(size_t N, size_t parent[static N]) {
    parent[N] = N;
}

#define SIZE 10

int main() {
    size_t parent[SIZE];
    genset(SIZE, parent);
}

I tried compiling with “static” replaced with “size_t” but it still fails with another error.

Unrelated, but parent[N] = N will write out of bounds.

As for your problem, it seems that static in that context is only usable with actual compile-time constant values, not for VLA's.

I can’t reproduce the issue: your code compiles for me on clang and GCC. You need to provide more details about your compiler invocation.

@KonradRudolph My bad, code was compiled using tcc.

tcc only implements a subset of C99. static array indices are not yet supported. However, the development version of tcc does support them.
